# in what program could I code a .sh file in Windows

Tags: linux, windows, bash, shell

What program could I use in Windows to write a .sh file. When I execute the .sh I get `$'\r': command not found`

Been searching to find this is due to the .sh file written in windows, which program and or setting to use so that .sh can be written and executed in linux without that error.

Comment: Sorry, questions asking to recommend tools are discouraged here on SO -- please read the *On-topic* FAQ page!

Comment: .sh files stands for shell scripts used in linux machine. In windows .bat files are popular for scripting

Comment: yeah, yeah, the precise question is how to get to code .sh under a windows os.

Answer (score 2):

The exact program is irrelevant, so long as it is a text editor supports Unix line endings (LF). When a file is saved with MS-DOS line endings (CRLF), the shell will try to interpret the CR as a command, which will result in the error shown.

Comment: allright, awesome. anyway for 90% of the world population that's on windows to write .sh ?

Comment: Yes. Use a text editor that supports Unix line endings. There are hundreds.

Comment: The 1% of the 90% who actually write shell scripts on Windows at all probably use a popular programmer's text editor like Emacs or Vim.